# Finding a Substring in a Dataframe from a Numpy Array?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

How do I find a list of substrings in a dataframe against an array and use the array values to create a new column? For example, I started off using `str.contains` and typing out the actual string value(see below).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#Filepath directory
csv_report = filepath

#Creates dataframe of CSV report
csv_df = pd.read_csv(csv_report)
  
csv_df['animal'] = np.where(csv_df.item_name.str.contains('Condor'), "Condor",
                   np.where(csv_df.item_name.str.contains('Marmot'), "Marmot",
                   np.where(csv_df.item_name.str.contains('Bear'),"Bear",
                   np.where(csv_df.item_name.str.contains('Pika'),"Pika",
                   np.where(csv_df.item_name.str.contains('Rat'),"Rat",
                   np.where(csv_df.item_name.str.contains('Racoon'),"Racoon",
                   np.where(csv_df.item_name.str.contains('Opossum'),"Opossum")))))))
```

**How would I go about achieving the above code if the string values are in an array instead? Sample below:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#Filepath directory
csv_report = filepath

#Creates dataframe of CSV report
csv_df = pd.read_csv(csv_report)

animal_list = np.array(['Condor', 'Marmot','Bear','Pika','Rat','Racoon','Opossum'])
```

Comment: I'm not sure that using an array here helps.  A list of strings is just as good.  Pandas doesn't use `numpy` string dtypes for its strings.  Columns with strings are object dtype, with Python strings.  Use string methods and pandas own string enhancements.

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO. It will be great if you can have a look at [ask] and then try to produce a [mcve].
In this case @Jonathan Leon was kind enough to produce an example for you. But you should always try to write data for your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a better way than using `apply` or several `np.where`. Have a look at [np.select](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html).
Here as on the other answer we are assuming that each row can have only one match

## Data

Stolen from @Jonathan Leon

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = ['Condor', 
        'Marmot',
        'Bear',
        'Condor a',
        'Marmotb',
        'Bearxyz']

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["item_name"])

animal_list = ['Condor', 
               'Marmot',
               'Bear',
               'Pika',
               'Rat',
               'Racoon',
               'Opossum']
```

## Define conditions for numpy select

```py
cond_list = [df["item_name"].str.contains(animal) 
             for animal in animal_list]

df["animal"] = np.select(cond_list, animal_list)
```

output

```sh
  item_name  animal
0    Condor  Condor
1    Marmot  Marmot
2      Bear    Bear
3  Condor a  Condor
4   Marmotb  Marmot
5   Bearxyz    Bear
```

## Case insensitive

Here you should change the last two lines with

```py
cond_list = [df["item_name"].str.lower()\
             .str.contains(animal.lower()) 
             for animal in animal_list]

df["animal"] = np.select(cond_list, animal_list)
```

Comment: Thanks @rpanai. How would I go about ignoring case sensitivity?

Comment: @doubledribble I added the example. Please consider reading the link I already posted [ask] and [mcve]. It will be better to ask just once instead to add subsequent requests.

Answer (score 2):

I think there's a cleaner way to write this, but it does what you want. If you are worried about case-sensitive, or full word matching, you'll have to modify this to your needs. Also, you don't need a np.array, just a list.

```
import io
import pandas as pd

data = '''item_name
Condor
Marmot
Bear
Condor a
Marmotb
Bearxyz
'''
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep=' \s+', engine='python')
df

animal_list = ['Condor', 'Marmot','Bear','Pika','Rat','Racoon','Opossum']

def find_matches(x):
    for animal in animal_list:
        if animal in x['item_name']:
            return animal

df.apply(lambda x: find_matches(x), axis=1)

0    Condor
1    Marmot
2      Bear
3    Condor
4    Marmot
5      Bear
dtype: object
```

Comment: @doubledribble if the answer was useful please upvote it.

Comment: Sorry, this is close. I still want to keep the item_name column--I just want to add another column that shows the match.

Comment: @doubledribble as long as you do `df["animal"] = df.apply(lambda x: find_matches(x), axis=1)` you have an extra column added to your original df.